# StateServer deployment in windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

We implemented the Session StateServer concept in web application. Its working fine in local pC(Windows XP).

The same build we deployed in windows server 2003.the build is not working consistently

Any one please tell us.

Comment: What does you Web.config setting look like for session?  ( take a peak at this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx )

Comment: <sessionState mode="StateServer"
      stateConnectionString="tcpip=SampleStateServer:42424"
      cookieless="false"
      timeout="20"/>
We use the above setting in web.config

Comment: Are you trying to set the web sever to use its self as a state server, or are you pointing a web server or cluster to this server?

Comment: web server to use its self as a state server

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the tcpip=SampleStateServer:42424" to localhost:42424 or 127.0.0.1:42424

if you are turning a web server into its own session server you need to make sure that you have the service enable and running...  i am trying to find some where that will help you install/enable session services...

> Out-of-process Mode
>
> Included with the .NET SDK is a
>   Windows® NT service: ASPState. This
>   Windows service is what ASP.NET uses
>   for out-of-process session state
>   management. To use this state manager,
>   you first need to start the service.
>   To start the service, open a command
>   prompt and type:

```
net start aspstate
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx

Comment: We tryed the following settings

<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="120"/>

again we get the same issue

Comment: not sure u need the sqlConnectionString unless mode="SQLServer"

Answer (score 0):

We follow the following steps and we start the service

Step 1:  Start Asp.net State Servcie
1. Go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services 
2. Select Asp.Net State Service.
3. Right Click on Asp.net State Service and choose start from popup menu.

Again we facing the problem in windoes server 2003 box